# In R, how do I find the optimal variable to maximize or minimize correlation between two datasets

Tags: excel, r, optimization, correlation

I am able to do this easily in Excel, but my dataset has gotten too large.  In excel, I would use solver.

```
Column A,B = random numbers
Column C = random number (which I want to maximize the correlation to)
Column D = A*x+B*y where x,y are coefficients resulted from solver
```

In a separate cell, I would have correl(C,D)

In solver, I would set the objective of correl(C,D) to max, by changing variables x,y and setting certain constraints (such as x,y both have to be positive numbers).

How can I do this in R?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I strongly suspect that this can be done by some kind of classical linear algebra approach (e.g. canonical correlations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_correlation ) -- you might ask on `stats.stackexchange.com` ...

Answer (score 9):

In R, you make a `function`, the output of which is the value that you want to maximize or minimize. One optimizer included in base R is called `optim()`:

```
    set.seed(1)
    A <- runif(100)
    B <- runif(100)
    C <- runif(100)

    # these are your x and y to optimize
    pars <- c(x=1,y=1)

    OptPars <- function(pars,A,B,C){
        D <- A*pars[1]+B*pars[2]
        -cor(C,D)
    }
    # optim is one of many R-ish ways to do Excel's solver
    # it minimizes by default (though you can tell it not to)
    # and that's why I told it to take -cor()
    optim(pars,OptPars,A=A,B=B,C=C)
```

If you want `x` and `y` to have constraints, include that in the function you're optimizing, e.g. `abs(x)` instead of `x`.

Comment: literally, replace `pars[1]` with `abs(pars[1])` if you want it positive. If `optim()` then spits you back some negative number for `x`, just take it's absolute value and you'll still know it's optimal.

Comment: gotcha, after the optim() part of the code I get (error in cor(C,D) : 'y' must be numberic.. thanks again

Comment: huh, I don't get that error. It works smooth for me. Are you running this exact code or some modified code? If it's modified, put it in your question as an edit and I or someone else will have a look

Comment: got it now, thanks for the help! now something more complicated.. if i wanted to add a constraint where pars[1] + pars[2] has to equal 1.. is that possible?

Comment: then you'd only have 1 element in `pars`, and the other, in the function, would be `1-pars`. Got it? And if you only have 1 parameter, then you want the `optimize()` function, rather than `optim`. See `?optimize`

Comment: in the problem i'm working on, im going to have five columns, the sum has to equal 1 and each number have to be between 0 and 1. thanks again.

Comment: then similarly, transform within the function you're optimizing to meet that criterion, e.g. with `pars` a vector of length 5, redefine in the function to: `abs(pars)/sum(abs(pars))`. Remember, you'll have to transform the answer `optim()` gives you in the same way. Now you're beyond my expertise in general, so I suggest you ask another question if you want to make this even more complicated- there is likely a better way than what I just said as well.